How to tell which pin is which on this toggle switch?
I'm working with 5646AB for my project. Can someone help me clarify which pin is which? I don't want to assume the top left one is 3 XD.



Use an Ohmmeter to determine which terminals are connected in each position of the switch.

@PeterBennett Thank you so much for the help! Do you also have any tips on how to confirm it on a multimeter? Do I use the continuity check/ohms and use one probe (for example) on pin 2 and the other probe on pin 6?

You could use the continuity check, or resistance measurement - the resistance of a closed contact should be under two Ohms.

See this image from your linked pdf:

So the toggle handle is opposite to the connections that are bridged.
It doesn't matter whether you call each side 3/2/1 or 6/5/4, they are equivalent, but in any case the pin number is also shown (the view is obviously from the rear):

The switch can also be flipped 180° about the bushing axis but the keyway will be on the opposite side.
In any case, you can and should confirm with a multimeter.

Thank you so much for your help and pics! Do you also have any tips on how to confirm it on a multimeter? Do I use the continuity check/ohms and use one probe (for example) on pin 2 and the other probe on pin 6?

@alxzhu Yes, exactly. Flip the switch to a known position (say lever "up" in the diagram at the bottom of my post- towards the keyway which is also up) and you would expect continuity between 2 & 1 and between 5 & 4, and none between 2 & 3 and 5 & 6. And the opposite with the lever "down". Beep = continuity.

Can you explain why it's the 3 and 6 equivalent? I found 1&2 and 4&5 but I have two different wires on 3 and 6 so I really want to know which is. which. I looked at the rear and I don't see a number but I found out the part is actually 5636 (not 5646) if that makes a different

What I mean is that you can swap (3 2 1) with (6 5 4) since they are electrically independent. As sets of 3.  The photo you have clearly says 5646. A 5636 would have only 3 terminals.

https://imgur.com/a/5i7vPNr here's an update of it if you're curious, I'm not 100% sure if I wired correctly so if you have advice pls lmk!

I have imgur blocked on most of my machines, but I suggest opening a new question that has that schematic shown clearly. I think I see issues.

got it thanks! i'll comment the link here

hey! This is the new question I posted https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/726389/did-i-wire-my-switch-correctly-in-my-circuit-diagram ! I definitely owe you a cup of coffee! Thanks for ur patience and help! I really appreciate it ;-;
